# The result of MySQL query is not being stored in an array

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I am trying to store the result of a MySQL query into an array then I want to display that array elements in to front end in open cart. the code is as:

```
public function getProducttoquatation($quatation_id)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT product_id AS product_id FROM ". DB_PREFIX. "quatation_products WHERE  quatation_id = '". $quatation_id. "'");

    $product_id=array();

   if($query->numrows)
   {
      foreach($query->rows as $row)
      {
        $product_id[] = array(
                            'product_id' => $row['product_id'],
                            'id' => $row['id']
                             );
      }
      return $product_id;
   }
   else
   {
      return false;
   }
}
```

here I found the error like:

> Undefined property: stdClass::$numrows

how to store this problem
here if I try to write like:

```
$product_id=array("58","69");
```

then return this array then it works properly.
but I want this values in the array should be dynamic from MySQL query.
how to solve this?

Comment: It should definitely be $query->num_rows instead of $query->numrows. Also are you sure $query is properly populated(I mean the query is returning your expected results)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(($query->num_rows)>0){
```

instead of

```
if($query->numrows){
```

**UPDATE 2 :**

```
public function getProducttoquatation($quatation_id){


            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT product_id AS product_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "quatation_products WHERE  quatation_id = '" . $quatation_id . "'");

$product_id=array();

            if(($query->num_rows)>0){
                foreach($query->rows as $row){
                    $product_id[] = array(
                        'product_id' => $row['product_id'],
                    );
                }
                return $product_id;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
public function getProducttoquatation($quatation_id)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT product_id AS product_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "quatation_products WHERE  quatation_id = '" . $quatation_id . "'");

    $product_id=array();

   if($query)
   {
      foreach($query->rows as $row)
      {
        $product_id[] = array(
                            'product_id' => $row['product_id'],
                            'id' => $row['id']
                             );
      }
      return $product_id;
   }
   else
   {
      return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: This will fail if 0 rows are returned because query will be `true`

Comment: if(!empty($query))
   { }   This also we can use